# Comparable interface using the compare method

Tags: java, comparable

Could anyone please explain me why the code below does not work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
    Comparable<Integer> q = new Integer(4);
    Comparable<Integer> o = new Integer(4);
    // Problematic line
    int j = o.compareTo(q);

    if (j == -1)
        System.out.println("yes");
    else
        System.out.println("no");
 }
```

but this one works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
    Integer q = new Integer(4);
    Integer o = new Integer(4);

            // Problematic line
    int j = o.compareTo(q);

    if (j == -1)
        System.out.println("yes");
    else
        System.out.println("no");
 }

  }
```

In other words when is the interface implementation interchangeable as opposed to the creation of a normal class instance? The error comes when I use the *compareTo()* method which is part of the *Comparable* interface and is implemented by all Wrapper classes such as Integers.

So I guess `Comparable<Integer> q = new Integer(4);` and `Integer q = new Integer(4);` should not make any difference. Could anyone please explain?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes.  A `Comparable<Integer>` is something you can compare to an `Integer` - not something that you can compare to another `Comparable<Integer>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter of the `Comparable#compareTo()` method is of type `T` where `T` is the generic type variable of the `Comparable` type. In other words, for a variable declared as `Comparable<Integer>`, the method will only accept an `Integer`. The argument you are trying to pass is declared as type `Comparable<Integer>` which is incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

A `Comparable<Integer>` can only compare Integer(s).

```
// This will work
Comparable<Integer> o = new Integer(4);
int j = o.compareTo(new Integer(4));
// of course j will be 0, because 4 is equal to 4.
```